# Workarounds for jsdom document.readyState being readOnly?

Tags: jsdom, readystate

I'm using mocha with jsdom for unit testing of a JavaScript library. One of the modules in the library has different behavior depending on whether or not the document is ready. In order to test that behavior, I need to simulate a document that isn't completely ready (i.e. it's `readyState` property is `"loading"`). The simple solution

```
delete document.readyState
document.readyState = 'loading'
// perform tests ...
```

doesn't work because jsdom treats the `readyState` property as readOnly. Even after that code the `readyState` remains `"complete"`

Has anyone come across any clever work-arounds for this limitation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like a browser, you cannot delete or set `document.readyState`. Just like in a browser, you can change what the getter returns by redefining it:

```
Object.defineProperty(document, "readyState", {
  get() { return "loading"; }
});
```