# Using Jest to test code that is supposed to run before document.readyState === "complete"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

### What I'm trying to do

I am trying to write tests for a piece of code that tries to

1. run immediately if the document is ready, or otherwise;
2. run when the document has finished loading.

It looks something like this:

```js
// this is inside a function that returns a Promise
// and it resolves when `foo()` is called
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  foo()
} else {
  window.addEventListener("load", () => foo());
}
```

Assuming `myFunction()` returns a Promise that is only resolved after `foo()` is called. Ideally, I'd want to write a test like this:

```js
// put the document in "loading" mode
document.readyState = "loading"

// use a flag to keep track of whether promise has resolved
let complete = false
myFunction().then(() => complete = true)

// check to see that promise has not resolved yet
expect(complete).toBe(false)

// trigger load event and then check to see that the promise is complete
document.triggerLoadEvent()
expect(complete).toBe(true)
```

### What I've tried

I know that Jest has a JSDOM environment, so I'm able to test the first case pretty easily. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to test the line:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => foo());
```

I know that there's a `jest.spyOn` [method](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname). But that only tells me that a certain method has been called. It doesn't allow me to simulate the state in which the document has not yet finished loading, and then subsequently trigger the `readyState` to be "complete".

Comment: are you asking how to mock `addEventListener()` to be able trigger it in controlled way? take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732903/stubbing-window-functions-in-jest

Comment: if you are asking in general how to test that then, well, I'd have two tests. for both cases I'd mock `foo()` so I could ensure if it has been called. and in first test case I'd mock `document.status = 'complete'` and checked if `foo()` has been called. for 2nd case I'd simulate `status = 'loading'`, called function under test, ensured `foo()` has not been called yet, then run `load` event handler directly to ensure `foo()` has been run after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, it's actually not as straight forward as some people would make it seem. The issue is that `document.readyState` property is read only - in both modern browsers as well as js-dom, the mock dom object used by jest.

To work around this take the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest) and use `Object.defineProperty` to overwrite document.readyState. To fully cover my implementation I'm also mocking document.addEventListener, here's an example of how my code leverages the approach :

```
// MyFunc.ts
export async function myFunc(something): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (['complete', 'loaded', 'interactive'].includes(document.readyState)) {
      resolve(_helper(something)); // in reality this _helper func is accessing the dom
    } else {
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>
        resolve(_helper(something)),
      );
    }
  });
}
```

```
// MyFunc.test.ts
import { myFunc } from '../MyFunc';

describe('myFunc', () => {
  const addEventListener = document.addEventListener;
  let mockReadySate = 'complete';
  let eventListenerMock;

  beforeAll(() => {
    // use beforeAll because you can't define twice
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'readyState', {
      get() {
        return mockReadySate;
      },
    });
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    // create a new mock before each test to reset call count
    eventListenerMock = jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation((event, callback) => callback());
    document.addEventListener = eventListenerMock;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    // manually restoring mock so that document.addEventlistener isn't
    // a reference to jest.fn
    document.addEventListener = addEventListener;
  });

  it('myFunc should return correct value if DOMContentLoaded hasnt been fired yet', async () => {
    mockReadySate = 'loading';

    const res = await myFunc('bla');
    expect(res).toEqual(true);

    const res1 = await myFunc('bla bla');
    expect(res1).toEqual(false);

    // in this case document.addEventListener has been called twice for DOMContentLoaded
    expect(eventListenerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });

  it('myFunc should return correct value if document.readyState is already complete', async () => {
    mockReadySate = 'complete';

    const res = await myFunc('bla');
    expect(res).toEqual(true);

    const res1 = await myFunc('bla bla');
    expect(res1).toEqual(false);

    // in this case document.addEventListener has been called twice for DOMContentLoaded
    expect(eventListenerMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  });
});
```

There are a bunch of good Stackoverflow questions related to this, for more context check out :

- [Does Jest reset the JSDOM document after every suite or test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805128/does-jest-reset-the-jsdom-document-after-every-suite-or-test)
- [Mocking `document` in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest)
- [Mock document in Jest test file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644563/mock-document-in-jest-test-file)
- [Workarounds for jsdom document.readyState being readOnly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059010/workarounds-for-jsdom-document-readystate-being-readonly)
- [Mocking `document` in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098009/mocking-document-in-jest)